# Fold a partially applied value constructor over a list?

Tags: haskell, fold

I have a type like this:

```
data MessageType = Debug | Error deriving (Show, Eq)

type Code = Int

type Info = String

data Message = Message MessageType Code Info
```

and a function that takes a string and returns a `Message`:

```
parseMsg :: String -> Message
```

So far I've written a rough state machine:

```
parseMsg line = fold (words line) Message
  where fold ("D":xs) msgCtr = fold' xs (msgCtr Debug)
        fold ("E":xs) msgCtr = fold' xs (msgCtr Error)
        fold' (code:xs) msgCtr = fold'' xs (msgCtr (readCode code))
        fold'' rest msgCtr = msgCtr (unwords rest)
        readCode code = read code::Int
```

But I'd rather do this in an actual `foldl` or `foldr`.

```
foldl (\msgVConstructor el -> msgVConstructor el) LogMessage (words line)
```

The idea is to fold a function `(Message -> String -> Message)` so that the accumulator, `Message` is partially applied across the words in the string. However, I get this error

```
Constructor ‘Message’ should have 3 arguments, but has been given none**strong text**
```

I'm taking this to mean that a value constructor can't be partially applied in a fold. Is there no way to do this?

Comment: This is not reall a `fold` at all, since the number of folds is fixed. By writing it this way, you make it - in my opinion - very hard to interpret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if I understand it correctly, you basically want to parse three arguments in a constructor. This is not really what a `foldr` or `foldl` is supposed to do. `foldr` basically is a *catamorphism* over a list. You replace the `(:)` with `f`, and the `[]` with the initial accumulator `x0`. But since the number of elements in a list is not known at compile time, the type of `f` always need to have the *same* type: `a -> b -> b` with `a` the type of elements in the list, and `b` the type of the output of the fold.

If we however take a closer look to the code you provide, this does *not* look like a `fold` at all. You basically have a constructor with three elements, and aim to convert these into a `Message`. You can do so by interpreting the arguments separately:

```
parseMsg line = Message (mtype st) code rest
    where (st : sc : sr) = words line
          mtype "D" = Debug
          mtype "E" = Error
          code = read sc :: Int
          rest = unwords sr
```

We thus *unpack* the `words` of the `line` into `st`, `sc`, and `sr`, and then process the first, second an remaining elements into parameters of the `Message` (with `mtype` a function that translates the string into the corresponding `MessageType`), it reads the second parameter as an `Int`, and finally generate the `rest` as `unwords sr`. These parameters are then used to construct a message.

Comment: But in theory isn't it possible to do this? For example, I could write a function that "folded" a value constructor over a list in a dynamic language. I'd assume the same is possible in Haskell, it just requires more effort.

Comment: @dopatraman: in case of a dynamic language the signature of the constructor should remain the same after every *iteration*.

Comment: It is possible to write a polymorphic recursive function that calls itself with different types for the various parameters.  It's not what we call a fold, and it's not the simplest way to solve your problem.